# Is it possible to create 2 forms in one modular page using Grav CMS?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, grav

I am really new to Grav CMS. I am having a problem creating 2 forms (contact form and application/register form) in one modular page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now do it with the Form 2.0 Plugin !

And it is really simple, if you have for example two module on your modular page, in your case, **contact form** and **register form**.

That mean you have two MarkDown files like this :

**contact_form.md :**

```
---
title: contact_form_modular
forms:
    contact_form:
        name: contact
        action: /home
        fields:
            -
                name: email
                label: Email
                validate:
                    required: true
        buttons:
            -
                type: submit
                value: Submit
        process:
            -
                save:
                    fileprefix: register-
                    dateformat: Ymd-His-u
                    extension: txt
                    body: "{% include 'forms/data.txt.twig' %}"
                    operation: add
            -
                message: 'Thank for contacting us !'
---

## Modular title

Here a form to contact me
```

And **register_form.md :**

```
---
title: register_form_modular
forms:
    register_form:
        name: register
        action: /home
        fields:
            -
                name: email
                label: Email
                validate:
                    required: true
            -
                name: password
                label: Password
                validate:
                    required: true
        buttons:
            -
                type: submit
                value: Submit
        process:
           - 
                email:
                    from: "{{ config.plugins.email.from }}"
                    to: "{{ config.plugins.email.to }}"
                    subject: "Contact by {{ form.value.name|e }}"
                    body: "{% include 'forms/data.html.twig' %}"
            -
                save:
                    fileprefix: register-
                    dateformat: Ymd-His-u
                    extension: txt
                    body: "{% include 'forms/data.txt.twig' %}"
                    operation: add
            -
                message: 'Thank for registering'
---

## Modular title

Here is a form to register to my app !
```

Then in your **contact_form.html.twig** file in the template folder of your theme, you put the following line to render your form :

```
{% include "forms/form.html.twig" with {form: forms('contact_form')} %}
```

And the same for **register_form.html.twig** :

```
{% include "forms/form.html.twig" with {form: forms('register_form')} %}
```

Of course if you wish to, you can make your own form.html.twig to be able to customize the look of your form, you put the new file in a forms folder in your template folder of your theme.

For example : *template/forms/register_form_template.html.twig*

And in your **register_form.html.twig** you change like this :

```
{% include "forms/register_form_template.html.twig" with {form: forms('register_form')} %}
```

I hope I have been clear but in case here the link to the documentation :

https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/forms#multiple-forms

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Here your better answer !